# Django - template - User in never authenticated

Tags: python, django, templates, authentication

User is never authenticated even when the user is logged in. Right sidebar always displays Not Loggedin.Do i need to return something to base.html? And how will i do that ? do i need a new function in views.py ? but there is no url for base.hthl. What i am missing?Please be specific i am in web dev. PS: i also tried if request.user.is_loggedin and some other

base.html

```
<div id="sidebar">
    {% block sidebar %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/notes/all">Notes</a></li>

    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="rightsidebar">
    {% block rightsidebar %}

        {% if request.user.is_authenticated  %}
            Loggedin
        {% else %}
            Not Loggedin
        {% endif %}


    {% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="content">
    {% block content %}This is the content area{% endblock %}


</div>
```

views.py

```
def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username','')
    password = request.POST.get('password','')
    user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
        else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/auth_view')
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')
```

Comment: what view renders the sample template (`base.html`)? you probably aren't using a `RequestContext` when rendering said template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated  %}
```

You need to do the following in you view:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def view(request):
    my_data_dictionary = {}
    # code here
    return render_to_response('template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def view(request):
    # code here
    return render_to_response('template.html', {},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Because you need to use context processors.

Comment: def auth_view returns other things. how can i return multiple variables or lists ?AND What is  my_data_dictionary, ???

Comment: Its just a dictionary of the values you want to use in your template. For example, if you queried a database and you want to show the queryset result, you will need to pass the queryset in you dictionnary. Anyway in your condition, just replace it with `{}`

Comment: `auth_view` is redirecting to other views. So you need to put this code in this url view `/accounts/loggedin` or `/accounts/auth_view`...

Comment: Can you post the view where you are rendering the `base.html` template?

Comment: Ok i try returning that from some other function.In staid of i template.html i return to base.html. right? I dont have a view for base.html cause i understand that in order to call a view you ll need a url in url.py. the base.html in extended by all other urls.

Comment: def loggedin(request):
     return render_to_response('base.html',
                            my_data_dictionary,
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: mate just add the code I mentioned `render_to_response(..., context_instance=RequestContext(request))`. In ANY view that uses `request.user.is_authenticated` in the template. I don't see where's the problem... It's a simple task...

Comment: but as expected i et error global name 'my_data_dictionary' is not defined. So i cant just replace that.

Comment: `my_data_dictionary` IS NOT DEFINED. Replace `my_data_dictionary` by `{}` only. I only gave you an example above...

Comment: Anyway if it worked, consider accepting and incrementing the answer.

Comment: Lad.What do i put in place of my_data_dictionary i don't have any context in def loggedin to respond to. i understand that i need to send some data to base.html in order to know the user. What can i send from def loggedin? All information is in auth_view but cant return anything more from it.

Comment: That's like the third time I tell you to replace `my_data_dictionary` by `{}`. Check my post update... That's my last comment, I tried my best... if you didn't get it to work, just go read Django docs.

Comment: OH MY GOD LORD . {} equals to everything in django ???????? it work after thsi long time. Thank so much . I have big problem understanding the simplicity of python and django !!!  Thank you so much.

Comment: No... `{}` is an empty dictionary. Because you have nothing to render you can pass an empty dictionary. Anyway don't forget to accept the answer. thanks.

Comment: Yes but only in loggedin.html display Logged in , although all .html files in application extends base.hmtl . That is big problem. I just need to display Logged in for all time that the user is logged in. Any ideas ?.

Comment: You do the same as you did in all views that requires login.

Comment: Seriously ? Their is no way to do this. there will be too many views. I thought that this is why we extends templates.  There must be a way to do this. The only way i could think of is to create a view only for base.html that works always . Do you think that i could create a view def base that calls and response to it selfs?

Comment: I don't see where's the problem? any view must return a rendered template with `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`. There's something you're not getting quite while, do over the django docs or some tutorials.